# how to stop calling more requests in vuejs

Tags: javascript, performance, rest, api, vuejs2

I have a little problem with my application in VUEJS.

I have an API build in DRF(Django Rest Framework), and application build in VUEJS, when I tested my API in postman working well because I just call one time and the response is one too.
When I tested in my app VUEJS, calling 3 times and more like this:
[image]

in first 3 rows calling almost correct, but my app in VUEJS calling many times like images.
my method is created like this:

```
created(){
 // this.DoTransPenalties();
},
mounted(){
  this.DoTransPenalties();
}, 
methods{
 DoTransPenalties(){
  console.log('transaction canceled ', this.transactioId);
 }
}
```

the method 'DoTransPenalties' is on mounted, in other cases, I put the 'DoTransPenalties' in created, but the same thing always calling many times,
and you can see the error GET, the API get a URL incorrect because the stranges characters in the URL.

please help me, could you say me if is the problem with the configuration of web pack or I need to use vuex, because I used vuex but the same problem.

thanks for your attention.

Comment: May you show the method where you make the call? The output is different from the code. If you could update and put the right method would be better. Because is suppose to print the transaction id. But from where did you get this value?

Comment: I edited my post please check there, the 'Dashboard' is the main component and the 'ModalOrdensVendaECompra' is the nested component.

Comment: Maybe would be better if I could see the component, and how you that call. In URL is like `%5BObject%20Obejct%5fD`, think it's something wrong into your argument handler or your properties is handling wrong